# Is there a way to allow only unique values in a column of an Infragistics UltraWinGrid?

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm using an Infragistics UltraWinGrid with a column of drop-down boxes. I don't want the user to be able to select the same value for multiple rows in that column. Is there a simple (or heck, I'd settle for advanced) way to do this?

I'm using VB.NET

-EDIT-

I tried setting a filter on the data source for the drop-down box. But when I did that, the values in the other boxes in that column started disappearing (not the values themselves, but the descriptions that they were supposed to represent, so instead of reading "Information", it just said "1"). All of the cells in a column refer to the same combo box, so if you filter out a value from the data source for one of them, you filter it out for all of them.

I'm currently trying to catch a CellChange event and check against all other currently-used values. If it was already used, I would put up a message saying as much and revert back to the old value. However, the value comes back as the previously-saved one, so... not helpful. About to see if I can use the "text" property.

Comment: As @lee-m said in its answer try to use BeforeCellUpdate instead of CellChange. Perhaps you could revert to the previous valute there. Moreover the solution from lee-m could be used if you leave out the remove item part. Of course you need to check if the value has been selected elsewhere in your rows.

Comment: Mark the answer from @lee-m as accepted because is his idea!

Comment: I'll consider it, though I think his idea was to re-filter the source, which wasn't what I did. The only thing I took from him @lee-m was using BeforeCellUpdate instead of CellChange which just made my solution a bit prettier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Infragistics, you could use an UltraDropDown which is bound to a DataTable (or something similiar) which you can add a "Selected" column in addition to a column holding the values you want to show.

As each value is selected (via `AfterCellUpdate` or `AfterCellListCloseUp` for instance), you could update the "Selected" column in that data source and use a column filter to only show items which haven't been marked as selected. That way as items are selected or removed, the contents of the drop-down would be automatically updated.

To clear the selected flag from the old value, you can use the `BeforeCellUpdate` event to access the cell's current value then perform a lookup on the data source bound to the UltraDropDown using that value to clear the flag.

Comment: Smart, but it's not clear how to restore the previous selected item to zero where the user changes the current item selected in the UltraDropDown.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide one possible method of clearing the selected flag.

Comment: Good thought. But when I tried that, the values in the other boxes in that column started disappearing (not the values themselves, but the descriptions that they were supposed to represent, so instead of reading "Information", it just said "1"). All of the cells in a column refer to the same combo box, so if you filter out a value from the data source for one of them, you filter it out for all of them.

Comment: Have you tried the approach Brian Fallon posted in the Infragistics forums: http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/p/22177/80778.aspx#80778

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

The trick was to use BeforeCellUpdate whose BeforeCellUpdateEventArgs has a "NewValue" and a "Cancel" member. I just look through all of the items in the column to see if any of them match the new value. If one does, I notify the user and cancel the operation.

And that's it. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub myUltraWinGrid_BeforeCellUpdate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.BeforeCellUpdateEventArgs) Handles myUltraWinGrid.BeforeCellUpdate
        If e.Cell.Column.Key = "myColumn" Then
            Dim newValue As Integer = CInt(e.NewValue)
            For Each row As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow In myUltraWinGrid.Rows
                If row.Cells("myColumn") IsNot e.Cell _ 'So I'm not checking against the current cell
                    AndAlso CInt(row.Cells("myColumn").Value) = newValue Then
                    MsgBox("That value has already been used in this column")
                    e.Cancel = True
                End If
                Next
        End If
    End Sub
```